# Array pointer arithmetic question

Tags: c++, c, arrays

Is there a way to figure out where in an array a pointer is?

Lets say we have done this:

```
int nNums[10] = {'11','51','23', ... };   // Some random sequence
int* pInt = &nNums[4];                     // Some index in the sequence.

...

pInt++;      // Assuming we have lost track of the index by this stage.

...
```

Is there a way to determine what element index in the array `pInt` is 'pointing' to without walking the array again?

Comment: Sorry, as currently phrased this makes no sense to me.

Comment: `int* pInt = nNums[4];` needs to be `int* pInt = &nNums[4];`.

Comment: Good spot. Pseudo code fail. :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes:

```
ptrdiff_t index = pInt - nNums;
```

When pointers to elements of an array are subtracted, it is the same as subtracting the subscripts.

The type `ptrdiff_t` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (in C++ it should be `std::ptrdiff_t` and `<cstddef>` should be used).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. You take the value of:

```
pInt - nNums
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ptrdiff_t delta = pInt - nNums;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question (it's not too clear)

Then

```
int offset=pInt-nNums;
```

will give you how far from the beginning of nNums pIint is.  If by

```
int* pInt=nNum[4];
```

you really meant

```
int* pInt=nNums+4;
```

then in

```
int offset=pInt-nNums
```

offset will be 4, so you could do

```
int value=nNums[offset]
```

which would be the same as

```
int value=*pInt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pInt - nNums
```

Also,

`int* pInt = nNums[4]` is probably not what you want. It will point to memory, address of which would be `nNums[4]`

Change it to

```
int* pInt = &nNums[4];
```

Comment: Um, NOT the last line. You're assigning the value in nNums[4] to an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @JonH, now the address of nNums[4] (type int*) is being assigned to a pointer that is dereferenced (type int). Type mismatch....